# convert Binary Search Tree to XML

Tags: java, xml, processing, binary-search-tree, data-visualization

I am trying to convert a Binary Search Tree into XML to draw it using Processing programming language. The problem I am facing is incorrect closing tags places.
This is the Java code that generates the XML

```
public void toXML() {
    Stack<String> tags = new Stack<>();
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    try {
        pw = new PrintWriter("tree.xml");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pw.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
    toXMLHelper(this.root, pw, tags, "root");
    while(!tags.isEmpty())
        pw.println(tags.pop().toString());
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
}

private void toXMLHelper(BSTNode<T> p, PrintWriter pw, Stack<String> tags, String place) {
    if (p != null) {
        addTag(p, pw, tags, place);

        if(p.left == null && p.right == null)
            pw.println(tags.pop().toString());

        toXMLHelper(p.left, pw, tags, "left");

        toXMLHelper(p.right, pw, tags, "Right");

    }
}

private void addTag(BSTNode<T> p, PrintWriter pw, Stack<String> tags, String place) {
    pw.println("<node place=\"" + place + "\">" + p.el.toString() );
    tags.push("</node>");
}
```

And here is the resulting XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node place="root">8
    <node place="left">4
        <node place="left">2
        </node>
        <node place="Right">7
        </node>
        <node place="Right">9
        </node>
    </node>
</node>
```

[image: This is the tree]

one of the bottom closing tags should be placed under of the closing tag of node 7. How can I fix it of do it better
I tried using XML encoder but it generate too much unnecessary tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to go over this the wrong way.
An easier approach would be to recurse over each element, instead of saving their tags in a stack.

There you go:

```
public PrintWriter bstToXML() {
    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("tree.xml")) {
        pw.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        bstToXMLHelper(this.root, pw, "root");
        return pw;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private void bstToXMLHelper(BSTNode node, PrintWriter pw, String place) {
    if(node == null) {
        return;
    }

    pw.println("<node place=\"" + place + "\">" + node.el.toString());

    if(node.left != null){
        bstToXMLHelper(node.left, pw, "left");
    }

    if(node.right != null) {
        bstToXMLHelper(node.right, pw, "right");
    }

    pw.println("</node>");
}
```

Hope it helps.